# leaflet sublayer on click event not under action

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I have created two feature-collection(polygon , multi polygon) layers and applied the on click event on both of them. layer2(which is above the layer1) is completely covering the area of layer1. So when i click on the layer2 , the respective click event is coming under action. And the click event of layer1 is not coming under action. what i want is that when i click on any layer , click event of both the layers should be triggered.

```
  layer1 = L.geoJSON(data2,{
                    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
                }).addTo(map);
                layer2 = L.geoJSON(data1,{
                    onEachFeature: onEachFeature2
                }).addTo(map);

                var overlays = {
                    "layer one": layer1,
                    "layer two": layer2
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

A way would be to listen on the `map` for the click event:

```
map.on('click',(e)=>console.log(e))
```